# Calendar from Google Calendar not syncing to the iPad

Tags: ipad, data-synchronization, calendar, google-calendar, google-sync

My iPad is really starting to infuriate me. My Google/iPad calendar sync has been working perfectly for months, but not it won't. In Google Calendar I've removed a few now superfluous calendars and added a new one to keep track of my classes. This new calendar just won't friggin show up in iPad. I've visited the [Google sync page for devices](http://m.google.com/sync) and everything is set up correctly. All my calendars are checked. But out of my 3 checked calendars, only 2 of them show up in iPad calendar.

I've tried removing my Gmail account from the iPad and re-adding it with no results.

Any ideas?

---

Debug progress: I've tried unchecking all my calendars (Except the mandatory main calendar) in the [Google Sync mobile page](http://m.google.com/sync) but they still show up in iPad. I've checked if the current calendars in iPad are synced, and they are indeed. I've also tried creating a new calendar with a few events on it and adding it to the iPad sync list via the [google sync page](http://m.google.com/sync). It doesn't show up on the iPad. So to sum up, the aforementioned sync page no longer has any control over which calendars are synced to my iPad.

Help still needed!

Comment: I'm experiencing similar problems & I found this page http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/static.py?page=known_issues.cs&&hl=en It says here that it's a known issue, hoe they fix it soon.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I unmarked to sync the calendar (deleted all events from the iPad) and then marked back to sync, and all got back to work.

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried. Annoyingly only the calendars that were syncing previously were added afterwards :3

Comment: @Codemonkey How many calendar and how many accounts are you tring to sync? And which are(n't) syncing?

Comment: It just happened again to me. I tried turning the sync on and off 3 times, and I let the calendar app in the front, so it could stay trying to synchronize. Also, I used the link provided by @BradleyChambers (in the other answer) while trying. Now it's working again :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but have you tried this: https://www.google.com/accounts/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Comment: I had not, but I have now. No difference in my problem. How was it supposed to help? :-)

Comment: I've seen that tool fix some weird syncing problems before.

Answer (score 0):

Go here and select all your calendars.

https://calendar.google.com/calendar/syncselect